# Looping through a Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, while-loop

I am having some trouble figuring this out. I would like to loop through all the months once, instead of twelve times as my code is doing so now. Can anyone help, also is there a more effective way of looping this funciton?

Thanks!

```
    window.onload = function() {
    getMonth();
};

 function getMonth()
{
var x="",i=0;
var month=Array();
month[0]="January";
month[1]="February";
month[2]="March";
month[3]="April";
month[4]="May";
month[5]="June";
month[6]="July";
month[7]="August";
month[8]="September";
month[9]="October";
month[10]="November";
month[11]="December";

   while (i<12)
      {
      x=x  + month + "<br/>";
       i++;
       }
    document.getElementById("months").innerHTML=x;
    }
```

here is a link to my jsfiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/priswiz/LqEE6/

Comment: You are just missing `month[i]` [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LqEE6/2/)

Comment: Here's a updated fiddle based on @Sushil answer, http://jsfiddle.net/knoxzin1/LqEE6/3/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use Array .join method.

```
var x = month.join("<br />");
```

your code will work if you use `x=x  + month[i] + "<br/>";`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to access the array by index

```
while (i<12)
{
  x=x  + month[i] + "<br/>";
  i++;
}
```

Currently, you are printing the value of month.